# How to put menubutton on the ActionBar

Tags: android, xml, menu, fragment

I have a problem with android ActionBar. I have created option which I can reach with the menu button. I'd like to use another button which is located on the ActionBar on the right side. I have read a lot about this and I tried almost everything but it doesn't work.

menu_gallary.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="hu.redbuttonebb.endi.fragmentek20.MainActivity">

<item
    android:orderInCategory="79"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom">

    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/create_new"
            android:title="Album hozzáadása"
            app:showAsAction="always"
            android:orderInCategory="100"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

GalleryFragment.java:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        menu.clear();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_gallery, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.create_new:
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                    "It worked ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

If anybody know what do I do wrong please response.

Comment: The overflow icon will automatically appear if you use `showAsAction:"never"` or if there is not enough space on the action bar

Comment: There is enough space and `showAsAction="never"` did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <item
  android:id="@+id/create_new"
  android:title="Album hozzáadása"
  app:showAsAction="always"
  android:orderInCategory="100"/>


<item
android:orderInCategory="79"
android:title="@string/action_settings"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow"
app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
```

Comment: Now I have two options ( Settings,Create new) when I click menu button. But there is no overflow icon.